# Как можно сделать скриншот выделенной области экрана?

Tags: c#, .net

Существуют ли готовые методы с помощью которых можно получить скриншот  области, которую пользователь выделил прямоугольником? В EnSO находил примеры получения скришотов всего экрана, что немного не то.

Comment: А каким образом юзер выделил прямоугольник?

Comment: @VladD вот это тоже 1 из проблем, которые я не знаю как реализова

Comment: Потому что если есть прямоугольник, можно получить большой скриншот и обрезать его

Comment: А вот этот ответ не покатит: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1163770/276994? Там можно выбирать часть изображения. (Отрисовка полупрозрачного окна без рамки — это отдельная история, довольно большая.)

Comment: @VladD, я похоже нашел исходники решения, которое базируется на том ответе https://www.codeproject.com/articles/21913/teboscreen-basic-c-screen-capture-application